# Laravel - How to resolve #message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL:

Tags: laravel

I have this query in my Laravel-5.8 Controller:

```
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;     
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $employmentTypeId = HrEmployee::where('id', $userEmployee)->where('is_active', 1)->first()->employment_type_id; 

    $all = DB::table('hr_leave_type_details')
    ->leftJoin('hr_leave_types', function($join) use ($employmentTypeId, $userCompany, $userEmployee)
    {
        $join->on('hr_leave_types.id', '=', 'hr_leave_type_details.leave_type_id');
        $join->on('hr_leave_type_details.employment_type_id', $employmentTypeId);
        $join->on('hr_leave_types.company_id','=', $userCompany);

    })
    ->leftJoin('hr_leave_requests', function($join) use ($employmentTypeId, $userCompany, $userEmployee)
    {
        $join->on('hr_leave_requests.employee_id', '=', $userEmployee);
        $join->on('hr_leave_requests.employment_type_id', $employmentTypeId);
        $join->on('hr_leave_requests.leave_status',4);

    })
    ->groupBy('leave_requests.employee_id', 'hr_leave_requests.leave_type_id')

    ->select('hr_leave_type_details.no_of_days','hr_leave_requests.employee_id','hr_leave_requests.leave_type_id', DB::raw('SUM(hr_leave_requests.no_of_days) AS approvedLeave'),DB::raw('SUM(hr_leave_requests.no_of_days) - hr_leave_type_details.no_of_days  AS availableleaves'))
        ->get();
```

When I ran the Code, I got this error:

> #message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `hr_leave_type_details`.`no_of_days`, `hr_leave_requests`.`employee_id`, `hr_leave_requests`.`leave_type_id`, SUM(hr_leave_requests.no_of_days) AS approvedLeave, SUM(hr_leave_requests.no_of_days) - hr_leave_type_details.no_of_days  AS availableleaves from `hr_leave_type_details` left join `hr_leave_types` on `hr_leave_types`.`id` = `hr_leave_type_details`.`leave_type_id` and `hr_leave_type_details`.`employment_type_id` = `1` and `hr_leave_types`.`company_id` = `1` left join `hr_leave_requests` on `hr_leave_requests`.`employee_id` = `17` and `hr_leave_requests`.`employment_type_id` = `1` and `hr_leave_requests`.`leave_status` = `4` group by `leave_requests`.`employee_id`, `hr_leave_requests`.`leave_type_id`) ◀"

How do I resolve it?
And where is '1' coming from?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in those lines:

```
 $join->on('hr_leave_type_details.employment_type_id', $employmentTypeId);

 $join->on('hr_leave_requests.employment_type_id', $employmentTypeId);
```

$join->on() method take always two column, not condition ....

i think you simply can use where in your join:

```
 $join->where('hr_leave_type_details.employment_type_id','=', $employmentTypeId);

 $join->where('hr_leave_requests.employment_type_id','=', $employmentTypeId);
```

more details about 'join->on()' in:

https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on

please let me know if it helps...